# Write results to permanent table in bigquery

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7, google-bigquery

I am using named parameters in Bigquery SQL and want to write the results to a permanent table. I have two functions 1 for using named query parameters and 1 for writing query results to table. How do I combine the two to get query results written to table; the query having named parameters.

1. This is the function using parameterized queries :

   ```
   def sync_query_named_params(column_name,min_word_count,value):
   query = """with lsq_results as
   (select "%s" = @min_word_count)
   replace (%s  AS %s)
   from lsq.lsq_results
   """ % (min_word_count,value,column_name)

   client = bigquery.Client()

   query_results = client.run_sync_query(query
   ,
   query_parameters=(
       bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter('column_name', 'STRING', column_name),
       bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter(
           'min_word_count',
           'STRING',
           min_word_count),
       bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter('value','INT64',value)
       ))
   query_results.use_legacy_sql = False
   query_results.run()
   ```
2. Function to write to permanent table

   ```
   class BigQueryClient(object):

      def __init__(self, bq_service, project_id, swallow_results=True):
           self.bigquery = bq_service
           self.project_id = project_id
           self.swallow_results = swallow_results
           self.cache = {}
      def write_to_table(
        self,
        query,
        dataset=None,
        table=None,
        external_udf_uris=None,
        allow_large_results=None,
        use_query_cache=None,
        priority=None,
        create_disposition=None,
        write_disposition=None,
        use_legacy_sql=None,
        maximum_billing_tier=None,
        flatten=None):

    configuration = {
       "query": query,
   }

   if dataset and table:
       configuration['destinationTable'] = {
           "projectId": self.project_id,
           "tableId": table,
           "datasetId": dataset
       }

   if allow_large_results is not None:
       configuration['allowLargeResults'] = allow_large_results

   if flatten is not None:
       configuration['flattenResults'] = flatten

   if maximum_billing_tier is not None:
       configuration['maximumBillingTier'] = maximum_billing_tier

   if use_query_cache is not None:
       configuration['useQueryCache'] = use_query_cache

   if use_legacy_sql is not None:
       configuration['useLegacySql'] = use_legacy_sql

   if priority:
       configuration['priority'] = priority

   if create_disposition:
       configuration['createDisposition'] = create_disposition

   if write_disposition:
       configuration['writeDisposition'] = write_disposition

   if external_udf_uris:
       configuration['userDefinedFunctionResources'] = \
           [ {'resourceUri': u} for u in external_udf_uris ]

   body = {
       "configuration": {
           'query': configuration
       }
   }

   logger.info("Creating write to table job %s" % body)
   job_resource = self._insert_job(body)
   self._raise_insert_exception_if_error(job_resource)
   return job_resource
   ```

How do I combine the 2 functions to write a parameterized query and write the results to a permanent table?Or if there is another simpler way. Please suggest.

Comment: I mean to ask, how to I pass the parameterized query in the write_to_table function ? As in, what should I be passing in the write_to_table() in place of query if I need to pass a parameterized query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be using two different client libraries.

Your first code sample uses a beta version of the BigQuery client library, but for the time being I would recommend against using it, since it needs substantial revision before it is considered generally available. (And if you *do* use it, I would recommend using `run_async_query()` to create a job using all available parameters, and then call `results()` to get the `QueryResults` object.)

Your second code sample is creating a job resource directly, which is a lower-level interface. When using this approach, you can specify the [configuration.query.queryParameters](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.query.queryParameters) field on your query configuration directly. This is the approach I'd recommend right now.